# Show that the Borel sigma-field is not generated by countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Define a collection $C$ of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ by $C=\{A\subseteq \mathbb{R}: $ either $A$ is countable, or $A^c$ is countable$\}$. Show that the Borel $\sigma$-field is not generated by subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are countable.

Hint: show that $\{\emptyset\cup\mathbb{R}\}\cup C$ is a sigma-field on $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt at a solution: I know that $[0,1]$ is on the Borel sigma field and $[0,1]$ is not countable, so obviously the two sets are not equal. But I still have to show that $C$ is a sigma-field and I'm not quite sure how the hint fits in. Why does the hint say to show that $\{\emptyset\cup\mathbb{R}\}\cup C$ is a sigma-field, and not just $C$?

Comment: Just follow the hint and prove that thing is a $\sigma$-field, call it $\mathcal{S}$. Later observe $\mathcal{S}$ does not  contain $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Note that $C=C\cup\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$. The hint is written sloppily.

Comment: So then, is there no need to show that $C\cup\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$ is a sigma-field? I can just show that $C$ is a sigma-field?